# Generic method "hides" non-generic one when calling

Tags: c#, .net, generics, interface, overriding

I am trying to call a method on an object that implements these two methods:

```
        public async Task<ServiceRequest> GetByIdAsync(int id)
        {
            return await _context.ServiceRequests
                .Include(sReq => sReq.ServiceResponse)
                .SingleOrDefaultAsync(c => c.ServiceRequestId == id);
        }

        public async Task<ServiceRequest?> GetByIdAsync<TId>(TId id, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default) where TId : notnull
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
```

The first method is from the interface `IRepository<T> : IBaseRepository<T>`

The second is from the extended interface `IBaseRepository<T>`

I am calling a method like this:

`ServiceRequest sr = await _sReqRepo.GetByIdAsync(serviceRequestId);`

It hits the second method and throws the NotImplementedException

Is there a way to explicitly call the first method?

I tried to explicitly call a method using interface variable like this:

```
IRepository<ServiceRequest> serviceRequestRepository = _sReqRepo;
ServiceRequest sr = await serviceRequestRepository.GetByIdAsync(serviceRequestId);
```

but it hits the the second method still.

Comment: what type is `serviceRequestId`?

Comment: @Daniel A. White its an int

Comment: Just to get it off the table: Is this yet another repository implementation on top of EntityFramework (Core)?

Comment: @Fildor yes its is. What's wrong with that?

Comment: @Fildor I am using Aggregates so Repository is a no-brainer here

Comment: are you sure that's what happening? can you press F12 (go to definition) and your call goes to the second method and not the first? because according to overload resolution rules and also according to my tests, the first method should be called, not the second, unless you are providing a value for the second parameter, or are specifying the generic type argument.

Comment: `GetByIdAsync(5)` should call the first, `GetByIdAsync(5, default)` should call the second, `GetByIdAsync<int>(5)` should call the second. `GetByIdAsync<T>(genericIntVariable)` would also call the second, but `GetByIdAsync(intVariable)` should call the first. `GetByIdAsync(genericIntValue)` would call the second though I think which might be your issue.

Comment: you say `serviceRequestId` is an `int`, but is it an `int` or is it a `T` where `T` is `int`? in the latter case you would call the second method not the first. if it really is a non-generic `int` then the first method should be called not the second. either way the number one way to fix this is to not overload the methods but use different names.

Comment: EF _is_ the generic repository. That's why. Putting one on top is widely considered an anti pattern.

Comment: Might we get to see the class in which you implement thoose interfaces?

Comment: It would also be importent to know where we get serviceRequestId from, due to behaivior already mentioned by @DaveCousineau

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As poeple pointed out in comments, it turned out the `serviceRequestId` was a `string`, that's why it was calling generic version of the method.